# Automatically resize UI elements with change in OS resolution

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface, browser

I am creating a website using Angular 9. However the UI elements look different(bigger in windows and fitting correctly in ubuntu) in two different Operating Systems. After digging deeper, I learnt it is happening because the display resolutions are different in both the OS (Windows 1366*768 and Ubuntu 1900*1080).
 I want to know how to handle this in Angular. i.e The website should adjust automatically with change in OS resolution. I am guessing if this could be solved by making my website responsive? Any lead would help a lot.

Comment: You can try css media queries.

Comment: @PrateekKumarDalbehera  could you please share me a link?

Comment: See this https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp. Good one to start with. You can create break points for the resolutions you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hope this will resolve my issue.

Comment: Please let me know if it works. But, typically, we use media queries to make the website responsive in smaller screens (mobile & tablets). I am curious to know how this will behave in bigger screens.